# Getting li content which include <a> tag

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve the complete html content from the li of a certain div(div1-this is a hidden div) and include it in a ul of another div

```
 <div id="div1">
      <li><a href="#text3">text3</a> </li>
 </div>
 .
 .
 .
 <ul id='list1'>
     <li><a href='#text1'>text1</a></li>
     <li><a href='#text2'>text2</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Output should be like this

```
 <ul id='list1'>
     <li><a href='#text1'>text1</a></li>
     <li><a href='#text2'>text2</a></li> 
     <li><a href="#text3">text3</a> </li>
</ul>
```

I am aware of doing like this,

```
var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{cccc}'>{cccc}</a> </li>";
```

find the last li from list1 and use after to append li to it

```
var hreftext = $("#div1").find("a").text();
li = $( tabTemplate.replace( /\{cccc\}/g, hreftext ));
lasttabnumber = Math.ceil($("#list1 li").length-1 );
lastTab = $( "#list1" ).find( " li:eq("+lasttabnumber+")" );
lastTab.after(li);
```

I would like to avoid this extraction and creation and rather get the value from div li as
 {< a href="#text3">text3< / a>}

I tried to get retrieve it using html, text, val, contents, find but nothing seems to be working or I am missing something.

Please let me know if it can be done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to move the `li`s, use

```
$('#div1 > li').appendTo('#list1');
```

If you want to copy them,

```
$('#div1 > li').clone().appendTo('#list1');
```

Comment: This will probably work, but it's slightly dangerous to use `>` in the selector since the HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<li>` outside `<ul>` or `<ol>` so it's possible that some browser will add it implicitly and the `>` selector doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The semantics of HTML tags do not impact selectors. This will select `li` which are children of `#div1`.

Comment: *Direct* children of `#div1`. The point is that if the browser turns it into `<div><ul><li>..</li></ul></div>` it doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, yes I see. Using invalid HTML will have its drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks, this would work for me. was looking at different angle itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/m8NhQ/2/)

```
var $item = new $("#div1").find("li>a").parent();
$("#list1").append($item);
```